# JS function scope defined in object not working for code coverage

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, qunit

I have a function which is defined in side an object. I have used Qunit to write test cases. When I try to generate code coverage report it gives me error var test is not defined.

JS file

```
$(function(){
var obj = {
        testFunction: function () {
            return true
        }
    }
});
```

Qunit tests case

```
QUnit.test("testFunction", function (assert) {
    assert.equal(obj.convertPostCode(), true, "We expect return true");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly $ being jquery, considers first param as a selector, but still executes the function but returns a jquery object back.

secondly, the obj is defined within that function scope and won't be available in your test scope.

to make it available, define obj outside either in the same level as the test or one or more levels above than the test, set its value inside the function inside $

example

```
   var obj;
$(function(){
 obj = {
        convertPostCode: function (postcode) {
            var len = postcode.length,
                index = 0;
            switch (len) {
                case 5:
                    index = 2;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    index = 3;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    index = 4;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return postcode.substr(0, index) + " " + postcode.substr(index);
        }
    }
});
```

Assuming the test is on the same level, you should now have access to obj

Comment: Yes it's Jquery function